# Checkout loader overlay not disappearing after page load completion

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript

We've recently upgraded a magento 2 site to 2.1.2 and since doing so the /checkout/ page has a strange issue. Once the page has completely loaded the loader gif does not disappear - it just stays spinning on the page.

How would I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: check console error.

Comment: There are no console or log errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be because you have an overwrite of `onepage.phtml` in one of your themes or modules.

I noticed in one of our upgrades, which was experiencing the same issue, that `#checkout-loader` div was missing the `data-mage-init` attribute.

This what the div attributes should look like:

```
<div id="checkout-loader" data-role="checkout-loader" class="loading-mask" data-mage-init='{"checkoutLoader": {}}'>
```

If you have overwritten onepage.phtml try this fix and use `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml` as a reference for any other discrepancies.

Comment: We do have a div `<div id="checkout-loader" data-role="checkout-loader" class="loading-mask">` but it doesn't appear to have the `data-mage-init='{"checkoutLoader": {}}'`

Comment: Correcting this worked perfectly.